# How to, on clicking back button, dismiss only the active dialog, not the dialog behind it?

Tags: android, dialog, dismiss

Hi I've been working on the creating a dialog by clicking a button on an already opened dialog.
*First Dialog's Name = dialog_main

Second Dialog's Name = dialog_edit*

First, I open dialog_main. There's a button on it which on pressed opens dialog_edit. 
When I click outside dialog_edit, it returns back to the dialog_main, which is what it is supposed to do.
But when I click the back button, it dismisses both the dialogs and returns to the main activity.

All I want is to make the dialog_edit's back button event return to the dialog_main. Please see the code.

```
    final Dialog dialog_main = new Dialog(ViewTask.this);
            dialog_main.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            dialog_main.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_main);
            dialog_main.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
            dialog_main.setCancelable(true);
            dialog_main.show();

      //button is a button displayed on dialog_main
      button_edit_details.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    final Dialog dialog_edit = new Dialog(ViewTask.this);
                    dialog_edit.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                    dialog_edit.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_edit_details);
                    dialog_edit.setCancelable(true);
                    dialog_edit.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
                    dialog_edit.show();

                    dialog_edit.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {
                     //do the operations
                     dialog_edit.dismiss();
                    });


                    dialog_edit.setOnKeyListener(new Dialog.OnKeyListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onKey(DialogInterface arg0, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

                        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
                            //do same operations
                            dialog_edit.dismiss();                  
                });


            }
            }); //end of button onclicklistener


    dialog_main.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog_main) {
                //Data is displayed from operations in dialog_edit
                dialog_main.dismiss();
            }
        });

        dialog_main.setOnKeyListener(new Dialog.OnKeyListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(DialogInterface dialog_main, int keyCode2, KeyEvent event2) {
                if (keyCode2 == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
                    //Data is displayed from operations in dialog_edit
                    dialog_main.dismiss();
                }
                return true;
            }
        });

}
```

There may be a few mistakes in the code, but I hope you get an idea of what I am doing. I have tried a few combinations of placing "dialog_main.dissmiss()" in other places, but the problem remains same.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution I can think of is toggling the cancelable property of the main dialog at appropriate places.

```
final Dialog dialog_main = new Dialog(ViewTask.this);
            dialog_main.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            dialog_main.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_main);
            dialog_main.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
            dialog_main.setCancelable(true);
            dialog_main.show();

  //button is a button displayed on dialog_main
  button_edit_details.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                final Dialog dialog_edit = new Dialog(ViewTask.this);
                dialog_edit.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                dialog_edit.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_edit_details);
                dialog_edit.setCancelable(true);
                dialog_edit.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);


                //mark main dialog as non-cancelable here
                dialog_main.setCancelable(false);
                dialog_edit.show();

                dialog_edit.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {
                 //do the operations
                 dialog_edit.dismiss();
                });


                dialog_edit.setOnKeyListener(new Dialog.OnKeyListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onKey(DialogInterface arg0, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

                    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
                        //do same operations
                        dialog_edit.dismiss();


                        //mark main dialog as cancelable again
                        dialog_main.setCancelable(true);                  
            });


        }
        }); //end of button onclicklistener


dialog_main.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog_main) {
            //Data is displayed from operations in dialog_edit
            dialog_main.dismiss();
        }
    });

    dialog_main.setOnKeyListener(new Dialog.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(DialogInterface dialog_main, int keyCode2, KeyEvent event2) {
            if (keyCode2 == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
                //Data is displayed from operations in dialog_edit
                dialog_main.dismiss();
            }
            return true;
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: yeah, your suggestion was helpful. I set the property         dialog_main.setCancelable(false); while declaring it first, and later changed it to true when dismissing the dialog_edit.

Comment: @victor if you could mark it as the correct answer, it would also help people who face similar problems. Thanks.

Comment: @victor btw if you declare your main dialog to be non-cancelable at the time of declaration i.e. before the edit dialog is shown, the back button will not work on main diag if edit diag is not shown and will start working only after edit dialog is shown and dismissed. In the solution above the back button's behavior will be consistent throughout.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it but I guess this will solve your issue..!
Replace the following Code..!

```
    dialog_main.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog_main.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_main);
        dialog_main.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        dialog_main.setCancelable(false);
        dialog_main.show();
```

Comment: dialog_main.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
dialog_main.setCancelable(false);
I need to keep these vales true.